# Ruby on rails with unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

What is the best deployment environment for a RoR app? Someone has suggested Unicorn but am not sure. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

well, i have a small app with just 3-4 pages and will be accessed by not more than 25-50 concurrent users. "best" here means, ease of deployment of the app and ease of maintenance of the environment itself. Obviously stability of the solution matters as well

Comment: Define what's "best" for you. Otherwise this can not lead to a constructive discussion.

Comment: well, i have a small app with just 3-4 pages and will be accessed by not more than 25-50 concurrent users. "best" here means, ease of deployment of the app and ease of maintenance of the environment itself. Obviously stability of the solution matters as well.

Comment: You should add that highly relevant information to the question.

Comment: Netbeans! Especially the 6.5beta or development version.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91445/best-ide-for-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @Brianjs What? That's an IDE, not a server technology.

Answer (score 2):

You should try passenger standalone, it uses nginx under the hoods and is lightning fast with little configuration. Especially when you use many apps on one server, with different gemsets and ruby versions.

Even using nginx under the hoods, you can still choose apache or nginx to maintain your webservers domains using sockets.

read this article:
http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/

Comment: Yep. Am reading through Phusion now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of ease of deployment and maintenance.

Then its hard to beat [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/).

It appears as an apache or nginx mod.

I always go for the apache mod
as I prefer to have apache installed from apt,
and I find it easier to do version upgrade.

It can be installed as simply as;

```
gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

And from then on the install process will tell you exactly what to do.